# Building a string before continuing in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach, tooltip, stringbuilder

I have some code used to set tooltip text in my program. Basically what happens is, the method is given a point which corresponds to the cursor position, and all the available tooltips under the cursor are combined and shown to the user in one tooltip.

What i'm trying to do is to build a string which contains all of the text from each tooltip under the cursor, and then set the tooltip text with that built string. My issue is that I want to build that string fully before continuing in the foreach loop. See my comments in the code:

```
public void Show(Point point)
{
    bool bInOldRegion = RectangleHitTest(point, oldRegion);

    if (!bInOldRegion)
    {
        oldRegion = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
        bool toolTipUsed = false;

        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in toolTipRegions)
        {
            var tte = (ToolTipEntry)entry.Value;
            Rectangle rect = tte.region;

            if (RectangleHitTest(point, rect))
            {
                sb.Append(tte.text + "\n");
            }

            // I want to finish looping over every entry value and 
            // building the final string before 
            // continuing with the "toolTip.SetToolTip" part below

                toolTip.SetToolTip(m_control, tte.text);
                toolTip.Active = true;
                oldRegion = rect;
                toolTipUsed = true;
                break;
        }

        if (!toolTipUsed)
        {
            toolTip.Active = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to keep it all within the foreach loop because I need to break at the end after the tooltip is set, in order for the tooltip to be shown correctly.

Comment: What is the type of "toolTipRegions"? Is it a Dictionary? or a HashSet?

Comment: toolTipRegions is a HybridDictionary

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why the following section could not just be moved outside the foreach loop.

```
toolTip.SetToolTip(m_control, tte.text);
toolTip.Active = true;
oldRegion = rect;
toolTipUsed = true;
break;
```

Perhaps because this isn't the complete source code and there might be complications with that.

If that is the case, please try the following alternate solution. The idea is to convert the foreach into a for loop and have it run 'n + 1' times where 'n' is the number of keys in the hashtable. And on the 'n + 1'th iteration we can have a check and run the above-mentioned code that you want to run at the very end. I hope this works for you, in case it doesn't, please do notify me of its limitations and we can work on a better solution.

```
        ICollection keyCollection = toolTipRegions.Keys;
        string[] keys = new string[keyCollection.Count];
        keyCollection.CopyTo(keys, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == keys.Length + 1)
            {
                toolTip.SetToolTip(m_control, tte.text);
                toolTip.Active = true;
                oldRegion = rect;
                toolTipUsed = true;
                break;
            }

            var entry = toolTipRegions[keys[i]];
            var tte = (ToolTipEntry)entry.Value;
            Rectangle rect = tte.region;

            if (RectangleHitTest(point, rect))
            {
                sb.Append(tte.text + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Mikaal, the reason I cannot extract the code outside of the foreach loop is because it causes the tooltip to flicker when there is no break statement. I had tried moving that piece of code into its own loop in order to use break, but it didn't have the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll test it out and let you know how it goes